# How to add Radio Button in PreferenceScreen in android?

Tags: android

How can I add a radioButton in the main PreferenceScreen in android ? I do not want to add ListPreference for the radio button option. Like CheckBoxPreference ,I want to add radio ButtonPrefernce in PreferenceScreen. Need Help!!!!!!!!!!!!

Rgds,
Praween

Comment: i never seen a radio button in a preference window in the way you describe it. You could make a window just come up with radio button choices... try looking at the "Checkable menu items" in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html.

Answer (score 4):

Create a new resource folder named xml in the app folder
Make use of ListPreference

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ListPreference
        android:key="@string/pref_key"
        android:title="@string/pref_title"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_default"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_values"
        android:entries="@array/pref_options"
        />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Create a resource file name arrays.xml in values resource folder

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="pref_values" >
        <item>popular</item>
        <item>top rated</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="pref_options" >
        <item>popular</item>
        <item>top rated</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

The pref_values acts as the keys for the options. While the pref_options will be the visible options. The default should be either of top rated or popular

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons must be in groups that's why you should a listpreference first. If you want to add only one radio button then use checkbox instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

u can add a radiobutton to preferencescreen.
pref.xml is the preference xml.

```
<PreferenceScreen
        android:key="prefkey"
        android:title="SETTINGS"
        android:summary="HELLO"
        />
```

Create a xml(radio.xml) with only radiobutton in it and place it in layout folder.

now in code:

```
onCreate(){  
PreferenceScreen root=getPreferenceScreen();  
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);   
PreferenceScreen pref= PreferenceScreen) root.findPreference("prefkey");   
pref.setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.radio);
```

}